# Knex event on transaction success

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I have a function that takes a transaction object as an argument. Can this function subscribe to an event that fires when the transaction is commited?

```
function createUser (data, trx) {
  trx.on('success', .. )
  return User.create(data, { transacting: trx })
}
```

I don't see anything like that in the source, if not inner/outer transaction can be used somehow.
https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/master/src/transaction.js

Comment: All i could found documented about events relates to the query builder itself, not transactions. http://knexjs.org/#Interfaces-Events maybe there is no way to attach events on transaction.

Comment: there is events on trxClient https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/master/src/transaction.js#L195 but doesn't seems to be the same as transaction

Answer (score 1):

I never found better solution. But transaction is event emmiter so you can override default knex functions to emit your custom event.

- Override commit to fire event.

  ```
    knex = require('knex')({...});
    const _transaction = knex.transaction;
    knex.transaction = (cb) => {
        return _transaction(trx => {
            const _commit = trx.commit;
            trx.commit =async  (conn, value) => {
                const out = await _commit(conn, value);
                trx.emit('commit');
                return out;
            }

            return cb(trx);
        })
    };
  ```
- Listen to commit event anywhere in code

  ```
   knex.transaction(async trx => {
        trx.on('commit', async () => {
            // fired after commit is done
        });

        await trx.select().from('users').update({...});
    })
  ```